# Free tunnel service that supports TCP through the tunnel (ie minecraft) to a permanent FQDN

Tags: minecraft, cloudflare, tunnel

I recently started using Cloudflare tunnels, and the Zero Trust dashboard in general, to expose stuff on my network that I want to use everywhere. This includes stuff like a filecloud server, a proxmox server, a git server, and more. I have a google domain name and use cloudflare nameservers.

I wanted to do the same thing with a minecraft server, but as far as my testing and research online, just using a TCP protocol with the hostname doesn't work. Ngrok is great for temporary solutions, but I want to be able to set and forget it. Are there any services like that, or perhaps recommendations as to how to make the cloudflare tunnel work? I've hit a bit of a wall.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help, but I tried this https://github.com/barbarbar338/ncfs and it works excellent. I followed [this](https://youtu.be/ZRV8c1aOCfc?si=GFU-rEc_sjhomZtM) and [this](https://youtu.be/ZvIdFs3M5ic?si=VAQYpza-gXTJYFdx) guide.

If you don't want to use Ngrok, maybe you find something here: https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling

... or here: https://github.com/search?q=cloudflare+minecraft&type=repositories

I hope it helped.